# How to connect a headset as a microphone, and speakers at the same time with only one cable

Tags: audio, cables, input, output

So, I recently bought a headset from Tritton, named "Kama", as I got home I noticed a unusual problem... The audio input and output are in the same cable.
I would really want to use this as both, but for some reason it just doesn't work as both.
I have tried playing with the settings and things but no luck so far.

Comment: Your question is off topic for this site.  I've posted an answer, but expect this question to be closed soon.

Answer (score 2):

The Kama has a four pole connector while your PC has one two pole connector for microphone and a 3 pole connector for earphone. 
If you check on Amazon, you will see an adapter recommended.  You'll need one of those to use the headset on a PC.